# How to check a public RSA key file

Tags: shell, openssl, rsa, public-key, pem

Inside a shell script I want verify public RSA file.
All I want to do is that find a way to check this file is a genuine public key file, nothing else.

Can I ask experts here what are the ways I can verify this input file to check this is a genuine public key file , not a regular file.

I will be using this public key file in future to validate an incoming encrypt gzip file but that is out of scope for now.

All I want is validate input file to check its genuine RSA public key file not an ordinary file.please note that I do not have any other files with me (eg : private key) .

e.g.: if the file is `‘public.pem’` I just want check inside that it’s a genuine RSA public key file not just a file with texts or file is not corrupted .
I’m already checking that file is not zero sized and md5 .

other possible checks I found 
check file got text `‘BEGIN PUBLIC KEY’` and `‘END PUBLIC KEY’`
Also found this command in google , Is there a better way to do this using openssl

```
‘openssl rsa -noout -text -inform PEM -in pubkey.pem -pubin’
```

Thanks

Comment: using openssl is probably the only way you want to do this. simply checking for the begin/end delimiters is pointless. I could send you a file with `BEGIN PUBLIC KEY heeheeheethisisnotvalidrsa END PUBLIC KEY` and your "verifier" would accept that.

Comment: exactly thats why i would like to know a better way to validay this public rsa file, please note that this a public RSA file of a remote server .

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's possible to use any public key format parser, including `openssl` or even parse key yourself as the format is not that difficult.

Command line tools set a non-zero exit code, when parsing fails:

```
openssl rsa -inform PEM -pubin -in pubkey.pem -noout &> /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    echo "this was definitely not a RSA public key in PEM format"
    exit 1
fi
```

Just to check any public key:

```
openssl pkey -inform PEM -pubin -in pubkey.pem -noout &> /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    echo "this was definitely not a public key in PEM format"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Assuming you mean Java (JRE) keytool, that cannot read a public key. A certficate yes, and an app can then `.getPublicKey()` from the cert, but publickey directly no. OTOH an app can directly read a generic (PKCS#8) pubkey in DER, but base64 less easily without an addon like BouncyCastle. As an aside, on `openssl` commandline `-inform PEM` is the default and can be omitted, and output options `-text -noout` can be omitted when you're discarding the output anyway; or with `-noout` and no other output option(s) you don't need to discard.

Comment: Yes, it looks like keytool cannot do that. base64 is supported both by `base64` utility, for example, and in Java by `javax.xml.bind.DataTypeConverter` class. I like to be explicit about formats and other things, there is not much gain in skipping format neither. You are correct that `-noout` and `-text` does not make sense together, but output still have to discarded, because there are possible error messages reported even with `-noout` option.

Comment: You're right I forgot about javax.xml, which wasn't there when I first encountered this issue. Although you actually need both base64 and the BEGIN/END handling, which is a few lines more. `-noout -text` do make sense *together* (to output the human-readable display without the encoded cert) and so do similar combinations like `-noout -subject -enddate`; they just don't make any difference when stdout is discarded. You're also right about discarding the error messages; I'm so used to them I hardly notice, but others will.

Comment: Note to future me: you could do `openssl pkey -inform PEM -pubin -in pubkey.pem -noout &> /dev/null || echo "this was definitely not a public key in PEM format"`

Comment: Is it possible to validate against a certification chain? To make sure the certificate (public key) came from a valid private key... Can't find in the answer :(

Answer (score 5):

The following script should work for all PEM-formatted keys and certs supported by OpenSSL. I have tested it on various valid and invalid ECDSA and RSA keys with matching and non-matching certs.

Save this as verify-cert-key:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
certFile="${1}"
keyFile="${2}"
certPubKey="$(openssl x509 -noout -pubkey -in "${certFile}")"
keyPubKey="$(openssl pkey -pubout -in "${keyFile}")"
if [[ "${certPubKey}" == "${keyPubKey}" ]]
then
  echo "PASS: key and cert match"
else
  echo "FAIL: key and cert DO NOT match"
fi
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x verify-cert-key
```

Run it on a cert and key:

```
./verify-cert-key server-crt.pem server-key.pem
```

Comment: I should note that running the commands and doing a visual comparison is quite easy

Comment: @ricardo-saracino does comparing the public keys visually when they are dozens of hex digits long and potentially off by one digit expose you to greater risk of error?

Answer (score 2):

Try this command if your public key starts with `-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----`

```
openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -in /path/to/pub_key.pem -noout -text
```

Comment: If the file only has `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` (PKCS#8), you can do `openssl rsa -pubin -in public.pem -RSAPublicKey_out | openssl rsa -RSAPublicKey_in -noout -text` to make this answer work.  It shows the modulus and exponent.