# Oracle PL/SQL function DBMS_CRYPTO.PKENCRYPT is throwing error when I try to encrypt using RSA public key

Tags: oracle, plsql, rsa, dbms-crypto

I'm trying to create a procedure that can encrypt input text using RSA public key provided by client, using the DBMS_CRYPTO.PKENCRYPT function.

Here is the sample:

```
DECLARE
  ip_str     VARCHAR (200) := 'Secret Message';
  pubkey     VARCHAR (2000) := 'samplekey';
  enc_raw    RAW (2000);
  kType      PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.KEY_TYPE_RSA;
  eType      PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.PKENCRYPT_RSA_PKCS1_OAEP;

BEGIN

  enc_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.PKENCRYPT
  (
    src        => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(ip_str,'AL32UTF8'),
    pub_key    => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW(pubkey, 'AL32UTF8'),
    pubkey_alg => kType,
    enc_alg    => eType
  );

  dbms_output.put_line('Encrypted : ' || utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(enc_raw ));
end;
/
```

```
But this is throwing me this error:
    ORA-28817: PL/SQL function returned an error.
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO_FFI", line 258
    ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO", line 143
    ORA-06512: at line 10
    28817. 00000 -  "PL/SQL function returned an error."
    *Cause:    A PL/SQL function returned an error unexpectedly.
    *Action:   This is an internal error. Enable tracing to find more
               information. Contact Oracle customer support if needed.
    *Document: NO
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you using a valid public key (not the literal `'samplekey'` you posted)? It seems to work if you do; though it doesn't like the comment lines (`-----BEGIN/END PUBLIC KEY-----`).

Comment: I'm using the key provided by the client. How can I verify if that's a valid key or not?

Comment: It should be a base-64 encoded value; the example I'm working with is 7 lines (6 of 64 characters, last one has 8, for 456 chars in total) plus the `BEGIN`/`END` comment lines - and like I said, it seems you need to remove those. You can verify [with `openssl`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26260514/266304), or there are online tools. (I guess as it a *public* key file you could include it, but... your client still might not like that *8-)

Comment: When run locally (so `dbms_crypto` is available) [this version](https://dbfiddle.uk/uJ_z1IIq) gets the same 'returns an error' message; [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/2kh1WL-R) without `BEGIN`/`END` works. (Also note that in 23c the `eType` needs `_SHA2` on the end.)

Comment: So I generated a 1024-bit public key using OpenSSL and it worked. The one I got from client is 512-bit and it's not working. Maybe this function doesn't support anything below 1024-bit key?

Comment: Any more you probably want at least 2048-bit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't get to decide the key size. I get the key from the client through an API. Is there any workaround to encrypt text using 512-bit or lesser bit RSA public key in PL/SQL? Open source is not allowed in my organization.

Comment: I don't think so. I can't find it documented but it does look like they've set the lower limit on key length to 1024. (I tried with a new 512-bit key and that failed too, so it's not just their key.) I wondered about handing off to a Java stored procedure but that is likely to have the same limitation. [Slightly related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51727995/266304) - "Some implementations got overly-protective and disallow key sizes smaller than (and sometimes including) 1024 bit."